# Scroll to top button not showing

Tags: jquery, html, css

My scroll to top button is not working on my other pages but it works on this page I can't figure out why. 
This is the fiddle that isn't working: https://jsfiddle.net/wzv5d3ab/
This is the one that is: https://jsfiddle.net/0s6721w4/
It isn't showing on the fiddle but it is on my server it may be a dependency

I tried to put the image in the same place.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
      $('#scroll').fadeIn();
    } else {
      $('#scroll').fadeOut();
    }
  });
  $('#scroll').click(function() {
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 600);
    return false;
  });
});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="img/icons/cloud.png" href="#" id="scroll" stye="display: none;"></img>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were different problems with the inline example and the fiddle. I'll address them separately.

First, in your inline example, you have an extra `}` in your JavaScript code, which is throwing an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }` error in the console and preventing your code from running.

Also added a large div so that scrolling can be tested, and fixed positioning for the `#scroll` div.

Working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
      $('#scroll').fadeIn();
    } else {
      $('#scroll').fadeOut();
    }
  });
  $('#scroll').click(function() {
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 600);
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='scroll' style='display:none; position:fixed; bottom:0;right:0; border:1px solid black;'>scroll to top</div>
<div style='height:500em; background:lightblue;'>asdf</div>
```

About your fiddle, here's what I had to change to get it working:

- you're using jQuery, but you didn't include jQuery. So in the console it was erroring: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`.
- uncomment the img #scroll tag in html
- remove `display:none` from css for `#scroll` (jQuery can deal with the inline style, but it can't cope with this
- uncomment background-color in `#scroll` so that img can be seen (since the src is not loading).

And a couple of other fixes:

- add `z-index:999` to `#scroll` so that it will be on top of images and stuff
- move `$(document).ready()` outside of the `for` loop.

After that I was able to get the fiddle working too: https://jsfiddle.net/1dgq9skf/

Comment: FYI I've edited my answer to also address changes to the fiddle to get it working, and a link to the working fiddle.

Comment: your fiddle seems to be not working, i just added the script without the bracket https://jsfiddle.net/hko83jy4/2/ and removed the comments from img tag from his fiddle and its working.

Comment: Strange, I must have forgotten to save my changes to the fiddle. I saved and updated the link. Thanks @AdityaThakur for the heads-up

Answer (score 0):

May be its because of `display: none`?
consider replacing it to:-

```
<img src="img/icons/cloud.png" id="scroll"></img>
```

Comment: @CodingOni see David784's answer, and remove href="#" from img.